# Local system account doesn't have read access to file

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions, file-history

I'm using File history, which is running as a Local system account. 
It can't read some of my files, but it should because Local system accounts have higher privileges than admin I believe?
[image: These are the original file permissions]

When I add the permission entry "Everyone", and give it full control, the file history service is able to back up the file. The file is sensitive so I'd like to keep it as secure as I can and not give everyone read access.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to edit the service or the Local system account so that it has access to the file?

Comment: Shift+Right click the folder and click Open Command Window Here. Then a command prompt will appear. Now type the command to take ownership of the file `takeown /f "FileName"` and then get the permission using `icacls "Filename" /grant Users:F`. Check if the issue gets resolved. If you are a local Administrator then you can use Administrators:F. F is the Full Control permission on the object.

Comment: @Wasif_Hasan, am I reading your suggestion incorrectly?  He said the file was sensitive..  giving access to everyone in the ***Users group*** is not a whole lot different than giving ***Everyone*** access.

Comment: Sorry, but all the local users are part of Users group?

Comment: I'd rather not give everyone access. What user group is Local System a part of? I also don't understand why local system doesn't have read access to the file in the first place.